# Probability of 1 number not getting spun in roulette for 243 spins?

Tags: probability

I would like to know what the chance in percentage is that a specific number doesn't get spung for 243 spins in a row.

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the roulette wheel has numbers $0$ through $36$ (i.e. $37$ possible outcomes), this probability is:

$$\big( \frac{36}{37}\big) ^{243} \approx 0.0013$$ (i.e. it's roughly $1$ in a $1000$ which, given the number of casino's and roulette wheels being spun each day, is surely a daily occurrence)

Here is [WolframAlpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(36%2F37)%5E243) for more decimals

Assuming that the roulette wheel has a double $0$ as well (i.e. $38$ possible outcomes), this probability is:

$$\big( \frac{37}{38}\big) ^{243} \approx 0.0015$$

Comment: What about double zero?

Comment: @BenjiAltman I know, some roulette wheels have just a $0$, others also have a $00$. That's why I made my assumption clear that there was just a single zero. But I can add the other case as well, sure!

Comment: In my country the game is played with one zero.

Quote
(i.e. it's roughly 1 in a 1000 which, given the number of casino's and roulette wheels being spun each day, is surely a daily occurrence)
Unquote

But not on a certain table spinning only 40 spins an hour and is open for 14 hours a day.

Comment: @AmroAwad Wikipedia says the single $0$ is 'European style' and the double $0$ is 'American style'